# Where can I find the XPSDrv Redist Package (XPS Essentials Shared Components)?

Tags: printing, driver, xps, redistributable

I'm developing an XPSDrv which is intended to be used in Win XP and 2003, therefore, I'm going to need the XPSDrv Redist package installed as a pre-requisite of my driver.

Indeed, if you look as the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463345.aspx#EHB) it says:

> The XPSDrv Redist Package (XPSEPSC) contains the system and driver
>   components that enable the XPSDrv printer drivers to be installed and
>   to enable the XPSDrv filter pipeline component to function. The
>   XPSEPSC will be redistributed via a executable package (exe). You can
>   access the XPSEPSC package and redistribution agreement through the
>   Microsoft Connect site, under the 'Windows Vista XPSDrv Driver
>   Redistribution'

The problem comes as I can't find XPSEPSC anywhere!! The connect program they suggest doesn't exist and the Windows 7 program I can find only had the .inf and driver files, no actual exe package.

I'm really surprised that no-one else is having issues with this!

I know I can use the XPS Essentials pack, but even this [MS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adrianford/archive/2008/08/01/where-to-get-the-latest-xps-print-path-bits.aspx) says you should use the Shared Components version:

> Note that although the XPS Print Path is included in releases of .Net
>   Framework 3.0 and later, and the XPS Essentials Pack, for print
>   drivers Microsoft recommends the XPSDrv redist package to ensure your
>   customers get the best experience.

Argh!! Any ideas anyone?

**Update**

I know that a blind link exists to download it, but does anyone know why there isn't an official MS download landing page for the shared components? Also, anyone know where the language packs for shared components are? (They are mentioned in the first link above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to ask an MS employee during a support request, and they suggest to use XPS essentials, not shared components, so there's the answer, don't bother with shared components! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dot Net 3 redist my friend, it looks like the package is part of it.

You can install the redistributable package from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=10CC340B-F857-4A14-83F5-25634C3BF043&displaylang=en see  X86 Redist Package

Or you can install .Net Framework 3.0 SP1 directly from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=EC2CA85D-B255-4425-9E65-1E88A0BDB72A&displaylang=en

Or you can install XPSEPSC

If you want to download XPSEPSC specific package you can get the x86 package here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=96332 .

Biblio: Where i got my sources. Also **Google Helped** :)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/47bee01a-6440-4c2c-afd2-04e9907712f0/
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/1b49eb80-093a-4201-982d-b525a5e90c70/
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/47bee01a-6440-4c2c-afd2-04e9907712f0/

Comment: Hey, being a native printer driver we don't need the .Net framework, so it'd be overkill for what we want. I've already found that blind link to XPSEPSC too, just seems really bizarre that there is no official google indexed MS download page like there is for the full essentials pack.